# What is futex-default-S?

Tags: perf

I can't find more info about `futex-default-S`

Is this a system call? module? or else?

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/06dc10eae55b5ceabfef287a7e5f16ceea204aa0/tools/perf/Documentation/perf-lock.txt#L102

```
      $ perf lock report -t -F acquired,contended,avg_wait

                    Name   acquired  contended   avg wait (ns)

                    perf     240569          9            5784
                 swapper     106610         19             543
                  :15789      17370          2           14538
            ContainerMgr       8981          6             874
                   sleep       5275          1           11281
         ContainerThread       4416          4             944
         RootPressureThr       3215          5            1215
             rcu_preempt       2954          0               0
            ContainerMgr       2560          0               0
                 unnamed       1873          0               0
         EventManager_De       1845          1             636
         futex-default-S       1609          0               0
```